# String manipulation, common filename conversion via a set of rules (example given.)

Tags: string, text, language-agnostic

## Language Agnostic.

Provide solutions in any language, common scripting languages preferred.

Process a string... We'll use these 4 in an array as examples.

```
examples = ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).tar.gz",
            "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).txt",
            "The quick & swift mule, kicks the lazy dev.txt",
            "Now we-come,to.the_payoff.txt"]
```

Transform it according to the following rules.

1. Initial word is always capitalised, regardless of any other rules.
2. Every word is capitalised, unless it is covered by rules 3 or 4.
3. Sub-strings which appear in a white-list are case preserved. In our example `["the", "JSON"]`
4. Sub-strings which appear in a black-list are purged from the string. in our example `["-CAT5","(",")"]`
5. The substring matching regex `/(\.tar)?\.[^.]*$/i` is always lowercase.
6. A list of punctuation e.g. `[" ", "_", ",", "-"]` are converted to ["."]
7. Multiple `"."` ie. `"..."` are replaced with a single `"."` (ie. squeezed.)
8. Separator ".", blacklist, whitelist should all be easily interchangeable, just supplying them as vars / arrays at the top is completely acceptable.

In this case we'd end up with:

1. `The.Quick.Brown.Fox.Jumps.Over.the.Lazy.Dog.JSON.txt`
2. `The.Quick.Brown.Fox.Jumps.Over.the.Lazy.Dog.JSON.tar.gz`

Answer is provided below, would like to see alternatives in other languages.

## Update

Added a couple more example strings to the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a beginner Perl programmer and here my attempt to do your task using Perl:

### Perl example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @examples = (
  qq(The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).tar.gz),
  qq(The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).txt),
  qq(The quick & swift mule, kicks the lazy dev.txt),
  qq(Now we-come,to.the_payoff.txt)
);

my @result;

my @whitelist = ( 'we', 'to', 'the', 'of', 'if', 'a', 'is', 'JSON' );
my @blacklist = ( '-CAT5', '(',')' );
my @separators = ( '-', '_', ' ', ',' );
my $separator = '.';

foreach my $eg (@examples) {
  $eg =~ s/(\.tar)?\.[^.]*$//pi;

  my $ext = ${^MATCH};

  my $blist = join('|', map { qr/\Q$_/i } @blacklist );
  my $slist = join('|', map { qr/\Q$_/i } @separators );

  $eg =~ s/$blist//gi;
  $eg =~ s/$slist/$separator/gi;

  my @vals = split /\./, $eg;
  push my @words, ucfirst shift @vals;
  foreach my $w (@vals) {
    $w = ucfirst $w unless $w ~~ @whitelist;
    push @words, $w;
  }

  $eg = join $separator, @words;
  $eg .= $ext;
  $eg =~ s/\.\.+/\./g; # squeeze
  push @result, $eg;
}

say for @result;
```

Comment: Check, does everything, +1 - I quite like, and am equally terrified of the way you transformed the blacklist and separators into (potentially huge) regexes. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby example

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

examples = ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).tar.gz",
            "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).txt",
            "The quick & swift mule, kicks the lazy dev.txt",
            "Now we-come,to.the_payoff.txt"]

result = []

whitelist = ["we", "to", "the", "of", "if", "a", "is", "JSON", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "HTML"] # you get the idea.
blacklist = ["-CAT5", "(", ")"]
separators = ["-", "_", ",", " "]
separator = "."

examples.each do |eg|

  extension = eg.match(/(\.tar)?\.[^.]*$/i)[0]
  eg.sub!(extension, "")
  blacklist.each{ |b| eg.gsub!(b, "") }
  separators.each{ |s| eg.gsub!(s, separator) }
  words = eg.split(".")
  words.each {|w|
    w.capitalize! if words.first == w
    unless whitelist.include? w
      w.capitalize!
    end
  }
  n = "#{words.join('.')}#{extension}".squeeze(".")
  result << n
end

puts result
```

Gives us...

```
The.Quick.Brown.Fox.Jumps.Over.the.Lazy.Dog.JSON.tar.gz
The.Quick.Brown.Fox.Jumps.Over.the.Lazy.Dog.JSON.txt
The.Quick.&.Swift.Mule.Kicks.the.Lazy.Dev.txt
Now.we.Come.to.the.Payoff.txt
```

Possible shortcomings, the whitelist and blacklist are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList final = new ArrayList();

String[] arr = input.split("[\\W]");

final.add(arr[0].charAt(0).toUpper() + arr[0].substring(1));

for(int i=1; i<length; i++)
{
    if(whitelist.contains(arr[i]))
    {
        final.add(arr[i]);
        continue;
    }

    if(blacklist.contains(arr[i]))
    {
        continue;
    }

    arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpper() + arr[i].substring(1);

}

String output = "";

int i=0;
for(i=0; i<finalList.size()-1;i++)
    output += finalList.get(i) + ".";

output += finalList.get(i);
```

Comment: How about the `/(\.tar)?\.[^.]*$/i` and `_ - , ' '` replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing better to do and playing with python ...

### Python example

```
import re

examples = (
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).tar.gz",
  "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.(JSON-CAT5).txt",
  "The quick & swift mule, kicks the lazy dev.txt",
  "Now we-come,to.the_payoff.txt"
)

result = []

whitelist = ( 'we', 'to', 'the', 'of', 'if', 'a', 'is', 'JSON' )
blacklist = ( '-CAT5', '(', ')' )
separators = ( '-', '_', ' ', ',' )
separator = '.'

for eg in examples:
    ext = re.search(r'(\.tar)?\.[^.]*$', eg).group(0)
    eg = eg.replace(ext, '')

    for ignore in blacklist:
        eg = eg.replace(ignore, '')

    for sep in separators:
        eg = eg.replace(sep, separator)

    vals = enumerate(eg.split('.'))

    words = [w.capitalize() if i == 0 or not w in whitelist else w for i,w in vals]
    words.append(ext)

    eg = separator.join(words)
    eg = re.sub(r'\.\.+', '.', eg) # squeeze

    result.append(eg)

for r in result:
    print r
```